# Why do the programs give me the wrong answer or "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"? What can I do?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, recursion

I was trying to complete the third problem of MIT's problem set 2 (The course is 6.00.1x, on Edx).
This is some information about the problem (as I said, I'm working on the third one, but I'll attach the picture of every problem because they are linked):
[image: Introduction]

[image: Problem 1.]

[image: Problem 2.]

[image: Problem 3.]

[image: Problem 3 test cases.]

I wrote to different programs and both of them don't work.
This is the first one:

```
savedBalance = balance
    def minimumFixedMonthlyPayment(balance,annualInterestRate, high, low):
        epsilon = 0.01
        minimumMonthlyPayment = (high+low)/2
        monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12
        savedbalance= balance
        for month in range(12):
            unpaidBalance = balance - minimumMonthlyPayment
            balance = unpaidBalance + (monthlyInterestRate * unpaidBalance)
        if abs(savedbalance-minimumMonthlyPayment*12) < epsilon:
            return print(round(minimumMonthlyPayment,2))
        else:
            if abs(savedBalance-minimumMonthlyPayment*12) > epsilon:
                high = minimumMonthlyPayment
            else:
                low= minimumMonthlyPayment
            return minimumFixedMonthlyPayment(savedbalance,annualInterestRate,high,low)
    minimumFixedMonthlyPayment(balance,annualInterestRate,(savedBalance*(1+annualInterestRate/12)**12/12) , balance/12)
```

The expected output is `29157.09`, but my program prints `2666.67`.

This is the second one, the expected output is the same but the program gives me an error: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`.

```
balance = 32000
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12
savedBalance = balance
low = balance/12
high =  (balance*(1+monthlyInterestRate)**12)/12
minimumMonthlyPayment = 0
unpaidBalance = 0
while savedBalance-minimumMonthlyPayment*12 > 0.01:
    minimumMonthlyPayment = (high+low)/2
    for month in range(12):
        unpaidBalance = balance - minimumMonthlyPayment
        balance = unpaidBalance + (monthlyInterestRate * unpaidBalance)
    if balance > 0:
        low = minimumMonthlyPayment
    else:
        high = minimumMonthlyPayment
    minimumMonthlyPayment = (high+low)/2
    if abs(balance) > 0:
        balance = savedBalance
print("Lowest payment is: " + str(round(minimumMonthlyPayment,2)))
```

The expected output is the same, but the program prints `2812.93`.
Where am I wrong? Why? How can I fix the program?
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: You can solve maximum recursion depth problems with [tail call elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Comment: try running it through a debugger and watch values. That would be my advice - for expected vs actual. know what to expect at each level of refinement